# Excel rotate (NOT transpose) a table 90 degrees clockwise

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

I have a table in Excel. How can I rotate (NOT transpose) a table 90 degrees clockwise?

Example

```
cell1  |  cell2  | cell3
cell4  |  cell5  | cell6
```

Expected

```
cell3  |  cell6
cell2  |  cell5
cell1  |  cell4
```

P/S: If I use transpose option when paste, I will have unexpected result

```
cell1  |  cell4
cell2  |  cell5
cell3  |  cell6
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean counter-clockwise ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want to do this manually, and that it doesn't need to be done via functions:

1. First transpose your range using the regular copy transpose paste function
2. Next, create an artificial sorting key (simply number is 1 to n) infront of the first column and sort in a descending order
3. Delete the sorting column you created in front of the first row

Comment: Yeah just `=row()` it and copy that down the column next to the transpose +1 for the easy option. I genuinely would have just delved straight in to building a macro (^o^)

Comment: If I was to do this via VBA I would most likely follow this same procedure :- )

Comment: I would add to an array from right to left then dump the array vertically

Answer (score 3):

**If you can use the new feature of SORTBY in excel,**
assuming your table sits in `A1:C2`, you just need to `=SORTBY(TRANSPOSE(A1:C2), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:C2)),-1)` to allow the data sorted by the natural reverse order provided by `COLUMN` after you transpose it.

Comment: This one-step elegant procedure worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go in a two steps process:

1. transpose your table (you have already done it)
2. "mirror" your table

To do this last step, consider that you have a table M rows x N columns, which is transposed into a N rows x M columns. The cell located at row ***i*** and column ***j*** has to be moved to the row ***i-1 + N*** and column ***j***.

In your example, after transposition cell 1 is in (1,1) with N = 3, and it will go to (1-1+3,1)=(3,1) and so on.

You need to use a short macro to do the transformation.

Comment: "mirror" your table ==> How can do it in Excel?

Comment: is your table with given M,N dimensions? or can it vary from time to time?

Comment: The table size is from C3 to AC19 (fix size)